# URL redirection in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, redirect

I have 2 pages **page1.html** and **page2.php**. I am sending user information (GET) like `page2.php?new_user=true`. In page 2 the first page has `id="Welcome`". In page2.php I am redirecting the request to a `<div datarole="page" > with id="NewUser"`(inside page2.php). I am using javascript to do this `$isnew= '<?php echo $_GET["new_user"]; ?>';`. Currently I am redirecting using an if condition

```
if($isnew=="true")
{
window.location.href="#NewUser"
}
```

The problem is I want to display #NewUser as a dialog and NOT a page. Can anyone give any other possible solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage('page.html', { 'role':'dialog'});` this will show it as a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

To show a page as a dialog:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#NewUser', { role:'dialog'});
```

[jQuery Mobile API - Dialog Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/)